# Issue related to routing in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have MVC webapplication.  i have written following rules in Route.config file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "about",
              url: "Home/About-WDI",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About"}
            );


        }
```

and in global.asax file, i have written following code:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

now problem is when i type `http://localhost:60123/Home/About-WDI`
it gives me error saying `Resources not found`

what is issue in above code? 
Thanks

Comment: The order of route definitions matter (the first match wins). Put the `about` route before the `Default` route

Comment: And what is the name of your action, About or About-WDI?

Comment: Default route always be placed last (most general one). The topmost route should be most specific route definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the order of the routes is taken into concern. And as your {id} parameter is optional the URL will be matched by the first route. So simply exchange both routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "about",
              url: "Home/About-WDI",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About"}
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```